# Read the width of a div with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to read the width of a div without jQuery. The code I'm using is:

JS:

```
var windowwidth = parseInt(document.getElementById("window").style.width);
window.onload = function start() {
    alert(windowwidth);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="window">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#window {
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 600px;
}
```

I don't understand why this isn't working, I've looked all over this site and google and can't figure out a solution. I don't want to use jQuery for this (it's a small custom HTML5 script so I don't need that huge library for one little thing) and even when I try the jQuery method, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Why not look in the jQuery source code to see how they did it?

Comment: Oo that might be a good idea if I can't figure it out another way, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not guaranteed that `document.getElementById()` will work (i.e. will return the required element) before the DOM is ready. So try:

```
window.onload = function() { // removed the name to avoid some IE leaks
    var windowwidth = parseInt(document.getElementById("window").style.width);
    alert(windowwidth);
}
```

Comment: That at least gave me the pop up, but it's giving me a value of NaN. Any ideas why? It works if I set the width inline, but I'd eventually like to release this for more than just me to use, and that might be a little confusing for people who don't read instructions.

Comment: @Rev, I genuinely recommend you include jQuery (or a micro framework that is much lighter) even if it's just for this one little thing. Chances are you'll use it in other places, but even if not, it's a small price to pay to not have to implement this yourself and test and continually support new browsers etc. Like you said, `.style.width` isn't the best solution, so you start using `.offsetWidth` which isn't standard, and the spaghetti begins...

Comment: Although you can try using `document.getElementById("window").offsetWidth`, not sure how it works with scroll and other such things (that a library would take care of), and like I said, it's not standard (although AFAIK widely supported)

Comment: This shouldn't work and if it does, then the code posted is incorrect.  You would have to use `getComputedStyle` and `currentStyle` with a combination of `offsetWidth` to get this to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

don't read the style property, read the actual width of the element:

```
window.onload = function(){
    alert(document.getElementById('window').offsetWidth);
}
```

`offsetWidth` is what the browser says is the width, which can be different than what you're setting it to with CSS if, for example, the content stretches it wider.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see how jQuery does it, here is the link to the source: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/dimensions.js

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery to do such a thing. You can find the exact thing you want right here: http://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score 0):

You can get style.width only after the element is drawn. Try to put your code to setTimeout(). Sometimes it helps me

```
window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(
       function(){ alert(document.getElementById('window').style.width); },
       200
    );
}
```