# Javascript width of div, returns 0

Tags: javascript, css

I m trying to retrieve the width of an div for my function with javascript:

```
#areaDraw {
margin-top:50px;
width: 50%;
min-height: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

and the function:

```
 Event.add(window, "resize", function() {
    sketch.resize(document.getElementById("areaDraw").style.width,   window.innerHeight);
}).listener();
```

somehow javascript always returns 0 for the width of the div(areaDraw)

so whats wrong with:

```
document.getElementById("areaDraw").style.width
```

Comment: I would recommend jQuery as it has a more robust `.width()` function, but if you are locked into pure JS. Use `offsetWidth`.

Comment: Posisble duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480125/read-the-width-of-a-div-with-javascript?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the width of a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787527/how-to-find-the-width-of-a-div)

Comment: For future visitors, it may be worth checking if your browser's developer tools panel is interfering with the element being measured. Try opening developer tools in its own window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `document.getElementById("mydiv").offsetWidth` instead of `.style.width`

Comment: works, and how can i get the Height? If i set #areaDraw to height: 30% for example?

Comment: instead of offsetWidth you would use offsetHeight

Comment: @EmSta give this a read as a refrence, http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

Comment: The thing is, i tried offsetHeight, but somehow it wont work!

Comment: @EmSta could you post your code in a fiddle? Would make helping you easier

Comment: I hope this snippet helps? The original code, is very long! http://jsfiddle.net/954ag/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33635/discussion-between-patsy-issa-and-em-sta)

Answer (score 4):

Use this instead:

```
document.getElementById("areaDraw").offsetWidth
```

Edit: As requested, an explanation of why this works (just as an extra reference).

It's because the property `style.width` is the width as defined explicitly in the CSS, wheareas `offsetWidth` finds the actual width of the element as it's displayed in the browser.

Comment: You could also explain **why** the first option did not work, and why this one does.

Comment: **or** you could read this answer, that does explain why :) http://stackoverflow.com/a/6480217/542251

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("areaDraw").offsetWidth
```

try this one :)

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

Your `#areaDraw` `div` element **is probably empty** at the moment you try to get the width of it.

`element.style.width` gets the **width of the content** of the element, regardless the `padding` or `margin` attributes.

---

### Solution

Try using the [`.offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetWidth)(*Source: MDN*) attribute. The difference is that it includes the **full width** of the element **with** its `padding` and `margin` attributes.

---

### More information

See the [MSDN example](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/offsetWidth.htm) along with [its reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534304(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using [`window.getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle)

```
var elem = document.getElementById("areaDraw");
var width = window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).width;
```

Take into account that width will be a string in this case (e,g '290.5px')

> getComputedStyle() gives the final used values of all the CSS properties of an element.

Answer (score 0):

Element must have style="display: block;" and My solution:

```
intId = 0;

function resize(con)
{
    var width = con.offsetWidth;

    if (width == 0)
    {
        var resfnc = function(con)
        {
            return function()
            {
                var width = con.offsetWidth;

                if (width == 0)
                {
                    return;
                }

                clearInterval(intId);

                resize(con);
            }
        }

        intId = setInterval(resfnc(con), 50);

        return;
    }

    //...... work here
}

var resf = function (con)
{
    return function ()
    {
        resize(con);
    };
};


var con = document.querySelector("#elementID");

window.addEventListener('resize', resf(con), true);
```